# change variables inside loop?

Tags: matrix

Well, Im new with this language and it looked amazing at first. But then I cant make a simple loop.
I mean, c'mon, I try to do the same outside the loop and everything works fine. Here is the code:

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, rhoPD = K11.rhoPD.K11  ]
```

(rhoPD and K11 are matrices).
I thought, maybe is because Im defining rhoPD with himself (a normal thing to do in an interation), lets try something else. But then I try:

```
 For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, rhoPD = a;]
```

AND IT DIDNT WORK EITHER. I tried clearing all variables, giving them values, but still got the error.
What the hell is going on? I mean, how cant I do something so incredibly simple?

Comment: Try to restart the kernel.

Comment: I mean, both is syntactically correct and executes fine on my machine. Anyway, you might (and should!) be interested in `Do`: It does essentially the same but more robust and it can autocompile. `For` is really only there for... *thinking deeply* ... for people coming from other programming languages who would complain that Mathematica hasn't any `For` construct.

Comment: Ah, and welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!

Comment: Why is your title "Tag times in Null is protected"?  It seems to have nothing to do with the code.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you mean by not working but when you run

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, rhoPD = a]
```

you should not get any errors. You should not get any results either, as **For** does the evaluation but does not necessarily print it. If you instead run

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, rhoPD = a]; rhoPD
```

you get the output

> a

---

For your original case, the problem is the initial value. Even symbolically, you need an initial value for such a self-referring definition (to my knowledge), hence a sloppy way to fix it is to use an auxiliary variable $a$:

```
a = rhoPD; For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, a = K11.a.K11]; a
```

gives the desired output

> K11.K11.K11.rhoPD.K11.K11.K11

One can use the scooping structure **Module** to make sure $a$ is not globally changed:

```
Module[{a}, a = rhoPD; For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, a = K11.a.K11]; a]
```

A better way is not to use **For**, but to use **Do**:

```
Module[{a}, a = rhoPD; Do[a = K11.a.K11, 4]; a]
```

which is shorter to write as we do not need the intermediate variable $i$.

However, all these are procedural approaches. A more organic way for this in Mathematica is just to use a functional built-in command. For the case at hand, **Nest** does the job:

```
Nest[K11.#.K11 &, rhoPD, 4]
```

> K11.K11.K11.K11.rhoPD.K11.K11.K11.K11